# access vue 3 app instance api from non-vue fiile

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

In vue 2 you can access the Vue instance Global api from .js files like this:

```
Vue.prototype.$auth
```

in Vue 3 you have the app instance, which as far as I know right now only exists within main.js

so if for instance, I have helper.js, how do I access `app.config.globalProperties.$auth` from the help file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could define a plugin :

```js
// plugins/auth.js
export default {
  install: (app, options) => {
    app.config.globalProperties.$auth={}
  }
}
```

then use it in `main.js`

```js
import authPlugin from './plugins/auth'

app.use(authPlugin)
```

Or try to export the `app` instance from the **`main.js`** and use it in your `helper.js` file :

```
export app;
```

**`helpers.js`**

```
import {app} from './main'
```

or you could pass that global variable when you call the helper function inside any component.

Comment: Thanks for the export `app` from main.js tip. In the helper function, after importing `app` from main, access the global properties using `app.config.globalProperties`.