# Vue 3 accessing vue instance in vue router. Outside a Vue file

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router, router, vuejs3

I'm stuck with this since awhile. I want to access my keycloak instance from within the vue router.js file.

```js
const preventRoutes = {
  beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
    console.log(App.$keycloak.authenticated); //here. (Undefined)
    if (store.getters.getLoginState === "true") {
      ...
    } else {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

[access vue 3 app instance api from non-vue fiile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66954284/access-vue-3-app-instance-api-from-non-vue-fiile)

I'm trying this solution. As it's the only VUE3 I can find, but still, I think he skipped some steps. Can someone simplify please?

Adviced Solution

```js
const preventRoutes = {
  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    next(vm => {
      // access to component instance via `vm`
      // console.log(vm.$keycloak.authenticated);
      if (this.vm.$keycloak.authenticated) {
        next();
      } else {
        next("/");
      }
    })
  }
}
```

main.js

```js
const myApp = createApp(App)

let initOptions = {
  url: KeycloakConfig["auth-server-url"], realm: KeycloakConfig.realm, clientId: KeycloakConfig.resource, clientSecret: KeycloakConfig.credentials.secret
}

const keycloak = Keycloak(initOptions)

myApp.config.globalProperties.$keycloak = keycloak;
myApp.use(VueAxios, axios)
myApp.use(store)
myApp.use(router)
myApp.mount("#app");

keycloak.init({
  onLoad: "check-sso",

  checkLoginIframe: false
}).then(async (auth) => {
  if (!auth) {

  } else if (auth) {
    router.push("/dashboard"); 
  }
}).catch((e) => {
  console.log('Serwer lezy: ' + e)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I have another solution (maybe its more a workaround, but it feels kinda correct)

You could wrap your router inside a custom plugin install method, like:

```
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHashHistory(),
    routes,
});

export default {
    install(app, options) {
        router.install(app)

        router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
            // access all used plugins
            console.log(app.config.globalProperties.$store)
            console.log(app.config.globalProperties.$First)
            // ... stuff ...
        });
    },
};
```

In your main.js you can just `use(...)` the router like before:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import * as plugins from "./plugins";

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(store)
   .use(plugins.First)
   .use(plugins.Second)
   .use(router, app) // add "app" as second param, that way you can access the store and every other plugin within the router
   .mount("#app");
```

Comment: well. I changed the whole authentication method because of this issue. Anyway, thanks a lot maybe someone else would need it.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is for `router.js` to export a function that captures a given `app` argument, which could be used either in a [route's `beforeEnter` hook](https://next.router.vuejs.org/api/#beforeenter):

```js
// router.js
import { createRouter as createVueRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

const createRoutes = (app) => [
  {
    path: '/restricted',
    component: () => import('@/views/Restricted.vue'),
    beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
                             
      const authenticated = app.config.globalProperties.$keycloak?.authenticated
      if (authenticated) {
        next()
      } else {
        next('/login')
      }
    }
  },
  //...
]

export const createRouter = (app) => {
  return createVueRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: createRoutes(app), 
  })
}
```

[demo 1](https://codesandbox.io/s/getting-app-instance-from-vue-router-hook-9kl8u?file=/src/router.js)

...or in the [global `beforeEach` hook](https://next.router.vuejs.org/api/#beforeeach):

```js
// router.js
import { createRouter as createVueRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

const createRoutes = () => [
  {
    path: '/restricted',
    component: () => import('@/views/Restricted.vue'),
    meta: { requiresAuth: true }, 
  },
  //...
]

export const createRouter = (app) => {
  const router = createVueRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: createRoutes(),
  })

  router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
                          
    const authenticated = app.config.globalProperties.$keycloak?.authenticated
    if (to.meta.requiresAuth && !authenticated) {
      next({ name: 'Login' })
    } else {
      next()
    }
  })
  return router
}
```

[demo 2](https://codesandbox.io/s/getting-app-instance-from-vue-router-hook-forked-o1j8f?file=/src/router.js)

Then your `main.js` would use it like this:

```js
import { createRouter } from './router'

const app = createApp(App)
const router = createRouter(app)
app.use(router)

const keycloak = /*...*/

keycloak.init(/*...*/)
  .then((auth) => {
    if (auth) {
      router.push('/dashboard')
    }
  })

app.mount('#app')
```

Comment: I really did man. Very precisely. I just forgot I undod this part before sharing it with you. https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-robinson-stc0n?file=/router.js Now it's giving me another error too. That createRouter can't be found in router.js. Anyway please if it's too much to ask you. You really tried to help ! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
//main.js
const app = createApp(App)
app.provide('app', app)

//router.js
router.beforeEach(function(to, from, next) {
  const app = inject('app');
  console.log(app.$keycloak.authenticated)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `beforeEnter` and the `beforeRouteEnter` **HAVE NO** access to the Vue instance.

You can either change your logic to use `beforeRouteLeave` that **HAS** access to the instance using `this` or you can add a callback function like:

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
  next(vm => {
    // access to component instance via `vm`
    console.log(vm.$keycloak.authenticated);
  })
}
```

On your specific case I would change the logic to use the beforeRouteLeave and prevent the `next()` function to be called in case the user is not authenticated.

You can find this information in more details here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards

Answer (score 0):

You can just append your route guard to your `main.js` file, which according to your code, becomes:

```js
const myApp = createApp(App)

let initOptions = {...}

const keycloak = Keycloak(initOptions)

myApp.config.globalProperties.$keycloak = keycloak;
myApp.use(VueAxios, axios)
myApp.use(store)
myApp.use(router)
myApp.mount("#app");

keycloak.init({...}).then(async (auth) => {
  if (auth) {
    router.push("/dashboard"); 
  }
}).catch((e) => {...})

router.beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
  console.log(myapp.$keycloak.authenticated); //here. (Undefined)
  if (store.getters.getLoginState === "true") {
    ...
  } else {
    ...
  }
}
```